# How can i set default values to array before results is added

Tags: arrays, laravel, model-view-controller, multidimensional-array, eloquent

i have standings method, where is all data from league matches.
For exmpl.

League one has 10 teams. And standings is calculated when results is added. But if some of teams doesn't have added results, they are not added to standings.

Main goal is to get all teams in standings, nvm if team hasn't any matches.
Before results is added, all results in standings should be 0 (points,matches,wins,loses and others)

here is my standings method:

```
public function standings(League $league, Team $team)
{
    $standings = [];

    $blank = [
        'points' => 0,
        'scoredGoals' => 0,
        'goalsConceded' => 0,
        'wins' => 0,
        'loses' => 0,
        'draws' => 0,
    ];

    $matches = Match::with('score', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
    ->whereHas('score', function($query){
        $query->whereNotNull('home_team_score')
            ->whereNotNull('away_team_score');
    })
    ->where('league_id', '=', $league->id)
    ->get();

    foreach ($matches as $match) {

        $homeTeamScore = $match->score->home_team_score;
        $awayTeamScore = $match->score->away_team_score;

        if (! isset($standings[$match->homeTeam->name])) {
            $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;
        }

        if (! isset($standings[$match->awayTeam->name])) {
            $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] = $blank;
        }

        $home = &$standings[$match->homeTeam->name];
        $away = &$standings[$match->awayTeam->name];

        $away['scoredGoals'] += $awayTeamScore;
        $home['scoredGoals'] += $homeTeamScore;
        $away['goalsConceded'] += $homeTeamScore;
        $home['goalsConceded'] += $awayTeamScore;
        switch ($homeTeamScore <=> $awayTeamScore) {
            case -1:
                // home lost
                // swap home and away and let it fall through
                $tmpHome = &$home;
                $home = &$away;
                $away = &$tmpHome;
            case 1:
                // home won
                $home['points'] += 3;
                $home['wins']++;
                $away['loses']++;
                break;
            default:
                // draw
                $home['points']++;
                $away['points']++;
                $home['draws']++;
                $away['draws']++;
        }
    }

    $standings = collect($standings)->sort(function ($one, $other) {
        if ($one['points'] !== $other['points']) {
            return $other['points'] - $one['points'];  // similar to desc
        }

        $oneDelta = $one['scoredGoals'] - $one['goalsConceded'];
        $otherDelta = $other['scoredGoals'] - $other['goalsConceded'];

        return $otherDelta - $oneDelta; // similar to desc
    });
    return view('admin.leagues.standings')->with([
        'standings' => $standings,
    ]);


}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the issue you are facing

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, the problem is that if the team has not played the match yet, it is not displayed in the standings array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can first fill your `$standings` collection with `$blank` item for all teams

```
$standings = [];

$blank = [
    'points' => 0,
    'scoredGoals' => 0,
    'goalsConceded' => 0,
    'wins' => 0,
    'loses' => 0,
    'draws' => 0,
];
$teams = Team::all();
foreach ($teams as $team) {    
    $standings[$team->name] = $blank;
}
```

And now you can omit following checks and initialization from the loop

```
if (! isset($standings[$match->homeTeam->name])) {
    $standings[$match->homeTeam->name] = $blank;
}

if (! isset($standings[$match->awayTeam->name])) {
    $standings[$match->awayTeam->name] = $blank;
}
```

This way you will have all the teams in `$standings` irrespective of their matches, later on your next loop will fill the related information for the teams who have played matches